# How do I set KDE under Fedora to use English instead of Danish in software?

Tags: linux, fedora

How do I configure Fedora 23 to English instead of Danish in the interface of all programs.

I am runnig Kde as the desktop, and in "System Settings"=>Translations I have "American English" as only preferred language. Most software and the kde interface inself is in english, but some software such as Firefox and Scribus are still running with danish text instead of english -((

**Added:**
Content of /etc/locale.conf is just the line:
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

locale gives me:

```
LANG=da_DK.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="da_DK.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Which explains why some programs think they should run with danish text. So now the question is: How do I change this?

I still want danish time zone, numbers and so on.

Also $LANG="da_DK.UTF-8" but $LANGUAGE="en_US" so is this a case of different toolkits having different ways to configure which language to use(So a Kde vs Gnome thing?)

Comment: did you restart your system? Firefox has ist own preferences of language under [Preferences -> Content -> Language](about:preferences#content) and if you once used Danish, it probably does not automatically switch.

Comment: The language setting in Firefox has nothing to its UI. It's for the `Content`, as it states itself.

Comment: @MTilsted Check the locale setting as this shows: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-System_Locale_and_Keyboard_Configuration.html#s1-Setting_the_System_Locale ; also with the command `locale`

Comment: @MTilsted Check `~/.pam_environment` and `/etc/environment` too.